# PhpStorm - Add summary to commit message

Tags: git, phpstorm, gitkraken

On professional git software like gitkraken, you are able to specifiy a commit summary message and a description.

[image: gitkraken]

It seems like in PhpStorm you can only write a description:

[image: phpstorm]

Am I missing it or is it not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous clients that do not offer fields for subject and description separately. The usual convention [goes like this](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/#separate):

> Separate subject from body with a blank line

Git itself will then separate the subject from the description for certain commands that are supposed to only show the subject (e.g. `git log --oneline`).